# Is it possible to programmatically check for connections between XIB objects and the IBActions/IBOutlets in a header file?

Tags: iphone, ios4

There are many instances where it would be cool to check or get a log summary of connections between various XIB objects and IBActions and IBOutlets from class files...is this possible?